# QUICK EASY: How do I print the link for the mp4 in this page?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, video, beautifulsoup

I am trying to navigate to the following page and print the link that ends in .mp4.

I can see the link under Chrome's Inspect > Network but I can't print.

```
https://www.learningcontainer.com/mp4-sample-video-files-download/
```

Desired link to be printed:

```
https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4
```

Code attempt:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.learningcontainer.com/mp4-sample-video-files-download/")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".elementor-video").click()
print(???)
```

PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
elem=driver.find_element(BY.CSS_SELECTOR,".elementor-video")
print(elem.get_attribute('src'))
```

Just print out the src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Steps :

1. get the list of all links in the web page, use `find_elements_by_tag_name("a")`
2. use `get_attribute('href')` for every link you found in the page.
3. for every `href` value check if it ends with .MP4

full code :

```
myLinks = find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
for mp4Link in myLinks :
    if (mp4Link.get_attribute("href").endswith(".mp4")) print (mp4Link .get_attribute("href"))
```